# Nine Patch With Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, nine-patch

Is it possibile to use 9-patch drawable with constraint layout? I'm trying to render an editable fraction. Two edittext separated by a nine patch drawable that is basically a black line that can expand horizontally:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numerator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/x"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        mr:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/denominator" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/denominator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/x"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        mr:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/numerator" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/fraction"
        mr:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/denominator"
        mr:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@string/numerator" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The line is rendered correctly, but it's not stretching itself, when numerator or denominator increase length. The drawable is working fine with "classic" layout (LinearLayout).

[image: Starting point]

[image: Expanded]

Link for [9 patch drawable](http://oi65.tinypic.com/24o8s1v.jpg)

EDIT: adding:

```
mr:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
mr:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
```

to View layout seems to work, now I need to center the content...

Comment: it is possible to use it with **any** `View`

Comment: Ok, could you please suggest me where am I wrong?

Comment: post two images: when your "length" is normal and when it is increased

Comment: @pskinkI've edited as requested.

Comment: Can you add your nine-patch drawable?  How is it defined?

Comment: @pskink replacing with a color results in nothing on the screen, just the two edittext with no separator at all. I've uploaded the 9 patch.

Comment: @pskink I don't get your point: using a 1dp height has the same result, nothing appears, anyway I need a 9 patch. The link is working fine for me, if you use Chrome, look in the center of the page, as the background is black.

Comment: ok now i see it, read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch. pay attention to "stretchable area"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in one of the constraints of the `View` used to display your nine-patch drawable:

```
mr:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@string/numerator"
```

You are trying to constraint the end of the `View` to a string resource and this actually doesn't throw any errors.

Since you would like this `View` to expand along with the nominator or denominator (whichever is longer) and your parent `ConstraintLayout` has `android:layout_width` set to `wrap_content` you can constrain the `View`'s horizontal constraints to `parent` like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fraction"
    mr:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/denominator"
    mr:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    mr:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    mr:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/numerator" />
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]